# How to open new Screen after ProgressBar loads in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

This is [what gets launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHUCx.png) from Main.java.

This is Main.java

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application 
{
    public static Stage mainStage;
    ProgressBar pb;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getStyleClass().add("root");
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setSpacing(20);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1024,768);

        ImageView appleIcon = new ImageView("apple.png");

        DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
        ds.setRadius(5);
        ds.setOffsetX(8);
        ds.setOffsetY(8);
        ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        appleIcon.setEffect(ds);

        pb = new ProgressBar();
        pb.setMinSize(400, 20);

        //This line is for CSS Class selectors
        //This line sets a class name for progress bar which I used css file
        pb.getStyleClass().add("red-bar");
        pb.setProgress(0);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(pb.progressProperty(),1);
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(new Duration(3000),keyValue);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.play();

//      if(pb.getProgress() == 1)
//      {
//          mainStage = primaryStage;
//          mainStage.setScene(new loginScene());
//          mainStage.show();
//      }


        root.getChildren().addAll(appleIcon,pb);
        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("progress.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

I want to launch another screen when the progress bar loads fully.

This is loginScene.java which calls loginPane's constructor

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class loginScene extends Scene 
{
    public loginScene()
    {
        super(new loginPane(),1000,700);
    }
}
```

This is loginPane.java. This is the screen I want to launch after the progress bar loads.

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class loginPane extends Pane
{
    public Stage mainStage;

    public loginPane()
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1024,768);

        Button bt = new Button("OK");

        root.getChildren().add(bt);
        mainStage = Main.mainStage;
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();

    }
}
```

I have tried bind() property of ProgressBar, but didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You absolutely should not bind anything to wait for the `ProgressBar` to complete! While your sample uses a timer to fill the progress bar (also a horrible idea), you should instead use the `ProgressBar` to actually show the progress of an underlying task. Once that task is completed, THEN you can open another window.  I'm not sure why you would show progress for something that isn't actually...something, but I recommend changing your approach.

Comment: If @Utsav Dave has asked what is the correct approach I would have suggested a more realistic approach of using Preloader(https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm) before showing the login screen. But I assumed he is in learning stage and possibly his question is to how to get notified when the timeline is finished. I am not sure what is his main intention whether a simple test or for an actual real application.

Comment: @Zephyr Even I know progress bars are used to load something in background, and when that action is finished something pops up. I don't know why people use such harsh words to let some beginner feel so bad

Comment: @SaiDandem people like you are more needed in programming community. People who help.

Comment: I'm not sure how recommending a different approach is considered "harsh," but your question is not very clear as to what your actual intentions were. Sai made an educated guess that turned out to be helpful for you and that's great! But being told you're doing something wrong is not harsh and not meant to be discouraging.

Comment: @Zephyr what you said in the first comment is indeed correct and I agree with that. But if you have suggested the details of "other approach" apart from the details of ProgressBar, it would definitely make it complete. May be just saying "change your approach" without giving much details makes the questioner to feel a bit low.

Comment: @SaiDandem - I can see that, I suppose. I must be channeling another SO regular today ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onFinished handler to the KeyFrame.

```
EventHandler<ActionEvent> onFinished = e->{
   mainStage = primaryStage;
   mainStage.setScene(new loginScene());
   mainStage.show();
};
KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(new Duration(3000), onFinished ,keyValue);
```

And a small correction needed to your LoginPane class.

```
class LoginPane extends Pane    {
        public LoginPane()        {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            Button bt = new Button("OK");
            root.getChildren().add(bt);
            getChildren().add(root);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To the one who downvoted :: I assume people ask questions to start learning by bits and pieces and NOT for a perfect solid approach/solution. From his question I understood that he is missing the information of "onFinished" part. And I just let him know.

Comment: not me this time - I tend to shout when (down)voting :) You might consider adding an aside to mention the thingies that should be on the OPs priority list for change, like fi.: java naming conventions (you corrected the one classname, but not the constructor), not extending scene/layouts/controls, not keeping public statics around. Beginners seeing an old hand repeating those base errors - completely normal for the early stage of learning - might get the impression that it's okay. Bad practices tend to spread quicker than good ..

Comment: I totally agree with you @kleopatra. May be I should be more clear with my corrections. Anyway updated the typo error.